# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x}{n\sin(\frac{x}{n})}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My thinking at the moment is try to show that the integrand converges uniformly on $[0,1]$ to $$f(x)=1$$ since I may then apply a theorem that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^bf_n(t) dt = \int_a^bf(t)dt$$ when $f_n$ is uniformly convergent. Is this the right approach? If it is, I am struggling with the proof that the integrand satisfies this condition of uniform convergence. And of course, if my approach is utterly wrong, please don't hesitate to suggest something else.

Comment: observe that $x/n\ll1$ for $x \in (0,1)$ and $n>>1$ therefor in the whole intervall of integration you might approximate $\sin(x/n)\approx x/n$ which makes your limit plain $1$ (you may also show with a bit of more rigour that corrections are of $\mathcal{O}(n^{-2})$)

Comment: I added a bit to my answer to address your uniform convergence idea.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $g$ is continuous on $[0,1].$ A fairly simple proof shows then that the functions $g_n(x) = g(x/n)$ converge uniformly to the constant function $g(0)$ on $[0,1].$ You are in the same situation: All we have to note is that $x/\sin x$ has limit $1$ from the right, so that we can regard it as continuous on $[0,1].$

Here's another approach. Make the change of variables $x=ny.$ The integral becomes

$$n\int_0^{1/n}\frac{y}{\sin y}\, dy.$$

We can regard the integrand as continuous at $0$ with the value of $1$ there. Apply the FTC to conclude the limit in question is $1.$

Comment: Looks like $\frac{F(1/n)-F(0)}{1/n}$ with the obvious limit.

Comment: It certainly does (was leaving something to the OP).